# Broken /etc/network/interfaces file

Tags: raspbian, networking, linux

So at first I had a problem with my Raspberry Pi connecting to any Wi-Fi connection because of an error which sounded like this: "no wireless interfaces found". I've tried several fixes but nothing worked and I ended up messing with the `/etc/network/interface`s file and now I can no longer connect to the Raspberry Pi via my ethernet cable and, because of the initial error, neither via my router. I don't have a cable to connect it to a monitor, so now I don't have any way to interact with my raspberry pi.

So is there a way to fix this file in Windows? And what about the lack of wireless interfaces found?

Comment: Yes, there is a way. If you mess things up, you can always reflash.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to fix it from Windows without extra (costly) software to allow Windows to update ext4 filesystems.

Your easiest fix is a fresh install of Raspbian Buster 2020-02-13 on a new SDCard booted in your RPi with the broken system mounted in a USB SDCard reader.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to fix this file from windows?

The short answer is, "YES". But you can't fix it by raspberry pi own. You should run a Linux OS (because windows don't support ext4 file system) on your windows box as a virtual machine (VMware workstation is my recommendation) and mount the raspberry pi's sd-card. Then, change the configuration as you want. I did it, just google the steps, though.

---

> What about the no wireless interfaces found?

"Follow the procedure below if you have write the Raspbian Buster."

Leave the `/etc/network/interfaces` with:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

# Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
# For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'

# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d
```

Other config files need to be a focus.

---

The vital part for you is that checking boot logs to find out the problem by opening:

```
/var/log/syslog
/var/log/*
```

Change the configuration and put the sd-card to the pi. The new log will be written and check again and again to find the solution.